# insert backward slash in mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, escaping

I am new to PHP. 
I am trying to insert '\' in my DB, but it doesnt work
Here is my code sample:

```
$mov_img_path = "out\\media\\img\\movie_banners\\$mov_name." . $img_extension;
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (mov_name,mov_img,mov_path,is_del,datetime) VALUES('$mov_name','$mov_img_path','$mov_video_path','$is_del',now())";
```

IN DB, it saves like this,

```
outmediaimgmovie_bannersapple.jpg
```

I am using double backward slash but still getting this, any idea?

Comment: use prepared Statements. That will escape Special character and prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using prepared statements, escape all values with (if u use mysql) mysqli_real_escape_string

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Please do this with ALL your values in All your queries. This is a major security concern.